# Append special characters in number EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm trying to give an edittext the format of a number I want

The input type of the edittext is number, but I need to append `-` and `/` when the user reach certain digits (3 and 10)

I have tried using

```
android:digits="0123456789-/"
```

In my EditText but is not working

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:digits="0123456789-/"
           />
```

And here the code I use to put the - or / while the user is writing

```
 txtNumber.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if(s!!.length == 3){
                    txtNumber.append("-")
                }

                if(s.length == 10){
                    txtNumber.append("/")
                }
            }
        })...
```

This does not workin, I want my output while writing to be like this

```
234-983482/3
```

But It does not work, I think its because the inputType of the edittext, but it needs to be number since I only need to type numbers inside.

If I change the if statment with `.append("4")` or any number, it works, but not for characters `-` and `/`

Comment: You might be modifying a copy of the input. Try setting the textview value after appending.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
if(s!!.length == 3){
   txtNumber+="-"
}
```